# Download error in QField

Tags: data, error, qfield, download, internationalization

I was not able to see the polygones and everything I worked on in the QField app in QGIS.
So I deleted the data from the local Storage. Since than it was stored in the Cloudan dI can see it on the Desktop Version in QGIS. Now I have the Problem, that I can't open the Project on my Phone. It says the Data is in the cloud but not in the locale storage. I get the error message: Packaging job finished unsuccessfully for .... Quota error. How can I reopen my data on QField? I already choose: prefer cloud in QGIS and updated the project. I also pressed the synchronisation button.